Sysbench - Worst FileIO on Fedora 41 than M1 Pro
I've been experiencing slow file operations recently. I did a bit benchmarking on my disk using sysbench.
Here is my Fedora 41 Result
samet@bequiet:~/dev/sysbench-dir$ sysbench fileio --file-total-size=32G --file-test-mode=rndrw --threads=16 --time=120 prepare
sysbench 1.0.20 (using system LuaJIT 2.1.1713773202)

128 files, 262144Kb each, 32768Mb total
Creating files for the test...
Extra file open flags: (none)
Creating file test_file.0
Creating file test_file.1
Creating file test_file.2
Creating file test_file.3
Creating file test_file.N
Creating file test_file.127
34359738368 bytes written in 18.05 seconds (1815.29 MiB/sec).
samet@bequiet:~/dev/sysbench-dir$ sysbench fileio --file-total-size=32G --file-test-mode=rndrw --threads=16 --time=120 run
sysbench 1.0.20 (using system LuaJIT 2.1.1713773202)

Running the test with following options:
Number of threads: 16
Initializing random number generator from current time


Extra file open flags: (none)
128 files, 256MiB each
32GiB total file size
Block size 16KiB
Number of IO requests: 0
Read/Write ratio for combined random IO test: 1.50
Periodic FSYNC enabled, calling fsync() each 100 requests.
Calling fsync() at the end of test, Enabled.
Using synchronous I/O mode
Doing random  test
Initializing worker threads...

Threads started!


File operations:
    reads/s:                      723.46
    writes/s:                     482.31
    fsyncs/s:                     1559.38

Throughput:
    read, MiB/s:                  11.30
    written, MiB/s:               7.54

General statistics:
    total time:                          121.5818s
    total number of events:              334145

Latency (ms):
         min:                                    0.00
         avg:                                    5.75
         max:                                   81.02
         95th percentile:                       17.63
         sum:                              1919987.05

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           20884.0625/704.61
    execution time (avg/stddev):   119.9992/0.01

samet@bequiet:~/dev/sysbench-dir$ sysbench fileio --file-total-size=32G --file-test-mode=rndrw --threads=16 --time=120 cleanup
sysbench 1.0.20 (using system LuaJIT 2.1.1713773202)

Removing test files...

Here is M1 Pro result
samettoolio@samet-MacBook-Pro ~ % sysbench fileio --file-total-size=32G --file-test-mode=rndrw --threads=10 --time=120 prepare
sysbench 1.0.20 (using system LuaJIT 2.1.1725453128)

128 files, 262144Kb each, 32768Mb total
Creating files for the test...
Extra file open flags: (none)
Creating file test_file.0
Creating file test_file.1
Creating file test_file.2
Creating file test_file.N
Creating file test_file.127
34359738368 bytes written in 11.86 seconds (2761.96 MiB/sec).
samettoolio@samet-MacBook-Pro ~ % sysbench fileio --file-total-size=32G --file-test-mode=rndrw --threads=10 --time=120 run     
sysbench 1.0.20 (using system LuaJIT 2.1.1725453128)

Running the test with following options:
Number of threads: 10
Initializing random number generator from current time


Extra file open flags: (none)
128 files, 256MiB each
32GiB total file size
Block size 16KiB
Number of IO requests: 0
Read/Write ratio for combined random IO test: 1.50
Periodic FSYNC enabled, calling fsync() each 100 requests.
Calling fsync() at the end of test, Enabled.
Using synchronous I/O mode
Doing random  test
Initializing worker threads...

Threads started!


File operations:
    reads/s:                      31728.32
    writes/s:                     21152.18
    fsyncs/s:                     67697.11

Throughput:
    read, MiB/s:                  495.76
    written, MiB/s:               330.50

General statistics:
    total time:                          120.0015s
    total number of events:              14468252

Latency (ms):
         min:                                    0.00
         avg:                                    0.08
         max:                                    8.37
         95th percentile:                        0.00
         sum:                              1192215.37

Threads fairness:
    events (avg/stddev):           1446825.2000/1926.25
    execution time (avg/stddev):   119.2215/0.01

samettoolio@samet-MacBook-Pro ~ % sysbench fileio --file-total-size=32G --file-test-mode=rndrw --threads=10 --time=120 cleanup
sysbench 1.0.20 (using system LuaJIT 2.1.1725453128)

Removing test files...

You can see the difference here.
Fedora 41 Specs:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 7950X - Zen 4, 16-Core, 4.5 GHz

Motherboard: ASRock B650E TAICHI AM5 EATX Motherboard

RAM: G.SKILL Flare X Series 64GB (2 x 32GB) DDR5 6000 (PC5 48000)

SSD: SAMSUNG SSD 990 PRO 2TB, PCIe 4.0 M.2

Operating System: Fedora 41 Workstation

Filesystem: EXT4


Macbook M1 Pro Specs:

CPU: Apple M1 Pro, 16GB

Operating System: macOS Sonoma 14.6.1


Same command, totally different results. I just wanna understand why I'm seeing this gap. Thanks.
